# Unregistering sidebar in child theme with no id

Tags: php, css, wordpress, parent-child

I have a child theme which changes the parent theme's footer (widget area). I copied the footer.php and changed it to include a new footer i registered/ativated in the child's functions.php

I use the unregister_sidebar( '  ' ); code to remove other sidebars from the parent.

PROBLEM: The footer widget area that the parent defines has no 'id' so I can't target it with the unregister code. Parent side-bar codes is as follows

```
function web2feel_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'web2feel' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h1>',
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Footer',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="botwid col-xs-6 col-md-3 %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="bothead">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
)); 
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'web2feel_widgets_init' );
```

I want to get rid of both from the back-end. I was able to target the first with its 'sidebar-1' id. But can't target the other.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, rather then unregister both as one does not have an ID have you tried removing the widgets action like below?

```
// Unhook default functions
function unhook_theme_functions() {
    remove_action('widgets_init','web2feel_widgets_init');
}
add_action('init','unhook_theme_functions');
```

Comment: it doesn't get rid of the back-end. The 'Footer'  is still called. Although now they are beside each other in the back-end not stacked like usual